# content move on browser height change

Tags: html, css

I've been working a lot with responsive webdesign lately, and I've come across a bit of an issue. I have a one-page based website, where I currently have 2 sections (pages) first one is the intro, and second one is "about me". Now, I had a couple of my friends to visit my website on their computers (1 being a laptop, which screen height is very low compared to my 24 BenQ) I want to ask how I can make my content static, so the intro doesn't sort of disappear underneith the "about me" section.

```
 .intro-container
{
    width: 70%;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#ContentWrap-2-about
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

these are the wrappers that sort of interacts the wrong way. You can visit www.old.vhammershoi.dk and scale down your browser to see that the box with the arrow in it (click and explore popdown) will move underneith the about me section

Thank you in advance

Comment: On which element? I tried to add a full-page wrap container and set it to position: absolute; - this made it work, but it also made my intro container to not fill out 100% of the view port

Comment: It would help if you gave us the relevant HTML. Possibly prepare the example in http://jsfiddle.net/ so its easy to play around and test. That way you reduce the effort needed to reproduce, and maximize your chances of an answer.

Comment: Well, there are a couple of images I used as background, so they won't display. But I've added the html and the css into this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/613u76jp/

Comment: I've just checked out the link, but you have a lot more (mostly CSS) mistakes going on than the one you ask a question about!

Comment: But do you have an idea how to fix the problem im asking about?

Comment: What mistakes are you refering to, Rvervuurt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off all, there is no need for custom height. You have set height to element with `overflow: hidden`, and because content is longer than element, button is pushed down. Remove height from all main elements, also, remove margin from `intro` container. In that way, button will be visible, and rendered page will be the same as without changes (except visible button)

[image]

Comment: Alright, I tried it out and it worked! Is it possible to use this method, and still display both sections as 100% of the viewport? I use #form1 in visual studio with 100% height, as well as body, html with 100% height. the about section is pushed down when "click and explore" pops out, and about 15% of the about section is visable on front page

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these to fix your DIV (intro container) to the top of the screen.

`position:fixed;`
`position:static;`
`position:absolute;`

Here is a working example : http://jsfiddle.net/19Lhchyy/1/

Using `postition:fixed;`

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
#ContentWrap {
    min-height: 100%:
    padding-bottom:30px;
}
#clickAndExploreText{
    position: absolute;
}
```

I dont know if ure able to position it but if you dont, your container will grow on hover
Then your Text 'Click and Explore' will never be under the following container.
aditionally you are missing some `white-space:nowrap` in your mobile version to prevent linebreak for the headlines and the tet 'click and Explore'